# jQuery - Change variable in function if element has class

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to change the `$someText` variable dependant on which banner is running the function.

I'd like banner-01 to show Some Text, banner-02 to show Some More Text and banner-03 to show Even More Text.

```
var $banner1 = 'Some Text',
    $banner2 = 'Some More Text',
    $banner3 = 'Even More Text',
    $someText;

$.fn.text = function() {
    $(this).append($someText);
}

$('.banner-01').text();
$('.banner-02').text();
$('.banner-03').text();
```

I was thinking some sort of if statement would work.  I'm just not sure how to implement this.

```
       if ($('.banner-01')) {
            var $someText = $banner1;
        }

        if ($('.banner-02')) {
            var $someText = $banner2;
        }

        if ($('.banner-03')) {
            var $someText = $banner3;
        }
```

This doesn't work, but it's sort of an idea.  Any help would be great!

Comment: What's the difference between this question and the one you've deleted? Same problem, same code (besides the strange jquery thing `$.fn.text = ...`), ... O.o

Comment: @Andreas Hi, It's tidier and clearer to understand.  I deleted that question because people were misinterpreting what it is I wanted.

Comment: You know you've effectively overwritten jQuery's `text` method,  which seems like a stupid thing to do ?

Comment: Hi @adeneo.  I was just using text as an example.  I wasn't thinking about it at the time.  text isn't actually going to be my function though

Comment: I think you're going about it the wrong way -> http://jsfiddle.net/Lzkqm3wp/

Comment: Hi @adeneo I'm not actually trying to append text.  I was just using that to explain it a little easier.  The variable will actually be a URL that will .load in content.  I just didn't want to confuse things (Which I'm sure I already have)  So I'm not sure this will actually work.

Comment: @adeneo This is sort of what I'm trying to do - http://jsfiddle.net/vz8j63kk/2/

Comment: You really are hellbent on making it complicated, aren't you -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vz8j63kk/3/**

Answer (score 0):

jQuery $() will always return an object. So it will never be false and all your tests will be true. You have to check the length of the returned object.

```
    if ($('.banner-01').length > 0) {
        var $someText = $banner1;
    }

    if ($('.banner-02').length > 0) {
        var $someText = $banner2;
    }

    if ($('.banner-03').length > 0) {
        var $someText = $banner3;
    }
```

Comment: `===` should be `>` otherwise this does not make much sense

Comment: Thanks @nanndoj This is what I was asking for, however it's only returning $banner3.  Do you have any ideas?  I've fiddled it here: http://jsfiddle.net/vz8j63kk/1/  Thanks for your help, it's really appreciated!

Comment: @Andreas - I couldn't add you to the above.  Thanks for your help!